# Using Purrr::Invoke() with Table and Chisq.Test to Improve Workflow

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
```

I'm trying to better understand the `purrr::invoke()` function. I feel like there's something simple that I'm missing that would help my workflow. I do admit I lack an understanding of "`do.call`", for which "`invoke`" is a wrapper.

As an example, I'm using the "`happy`" dataset from the `ggmosaic` package, but any dataset with a variety of factor columns will work.

I'm trying to use "`invoke`" to run some tables on selected factor columns, without success. I just want to be produce some simple tables based on a list of factor column names.

Something like this...

```
happy%>%invoke(table,list(c("health",c("happy"))

happy%>%select_if(is.factor)%>%invoke(table)

L <- list("health","happy","degree")
happy%>%invoke(table,L)
```

I'm also curious to know how I can incorporate `purrr::invoke()` into my workflow in other ways, for example, with `chisq.test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to iterate a function over the rows of a dataframe, I suggest you consider `transpose` + `map` instead of `invoke`:

```r
library(ggmosaic) 
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse) 

data(happy)

h <- 
  happy %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  sample_n(100)  ## use a subset for the example

h %>% 
  select_if(is.factor) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  map(table) %>% 
  mutate(h, TABLE = .) %>%  
  select(TABLE, everything())
#> # A tibble: 100 Ã— 11
#>          TABLE    id         happy  year   age    sex       marital
#>         <list> <dbl>        <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <fctr>        <fctr>
#> 1  <S3: table>   417    very happy  1975    68 female       married
#> 2  <S3: table>   529  pretty happy  1983    20 female       married
#> 3  <S3: table>   226  pretty happy  1973    32 female       married
#> 4  <S3: table>  1327 not too happy  1974    39   male       married
#> 5  <S3: table>  1632  pretty happy  1976    40   male      divorced
#> 6  <S3: table>    46 not too happy  1982    31 female       married
#> 7  <S3: table>   729  pretty happy  1994    85 female       widowed
#> 8  <S3: table>   557  pretty happy  1985    47 female      divorced
#> 9  <S3: table>   136  pretty happy  1978    48 female       married
#> 10 <S3: table>  1020    very happy  2000    21   male never married
#> # ... with 90 more rows, and 4 more variables: degree <fctr>,
#> #   finrela <fctr>, health <fctr>, wtssall <dbl>
```

But this result doesn't seem to be very useful - perhaps you could just `map` your summary to the trimmed dataset?

```r
h %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% map(table)
#> $happy
#> 
#> not too happy  pretty happy    very happy 
#>             9            50            30 
#> 
#> $sex
#> 
#>   male female 
#>     53     47 
#> 
#> $marital
#> 
#>       married never married      divorced       widowed     separated 
#>            53            25            14             7             0 
#> 
#> $degree
#> 
#> lt high school    high school junior college       bachelor       graduate 
#>             25             44              6             16              8 
#> 
#> $finrela
#> 
#> far below average     below average           average     above average 
#>                 6                25                41                16 
#> far above average 
#>                 0 
#> 
#> $health
#> 
#>      poor      fair      good excellent 
#>         4        13        41        18
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually just asked two more similar questions. It would be great if you could take a look at those too!